# Entity Framework Eager Loading Table-Per-Type Inheritance derived class

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, table-per-type

Using a table-per-type inheritance model and Entity Framework Code First, I am trying to eager load a list of derived class. Please note that I can't change the model.

I have the following model (overly simplified)

```
public class Training
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Students")]
public class Student : Person
{
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
}
[Table("Instructors")]
public class Instructor : Person
{
    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }
    public IList<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query Training by name and eager load all the persons including the derived class (Student and Instructor). Back in April 2011, Tom Dykstra [seemed to claim it wasn't possible](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

> The current version of the Entity Framework doesn't support eager loading for one-to-zero-or-one relationships when the navigation property is on the derived class of a TPH inheritance structure.

Has this changed? I am using EF5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why ...

```
var list = context.Trainings.Include(t => t.Persons)
    .Where(t => t.Name == someName)
    .ToList();
```

... shouldn't work. EF should populate the `Persons` list with concrete `Student` and `Instructor` entities.

You neither have a "*one-to-zero-or-one relationship*" nor is your navigation property (`Training.Persons`) "*on the derived class*". So, I think the mentioned limitation does not apply to your model and query.

Comment: I think, what was meant by the navigation property on the derived class is the IList<Training> Trainings (that I forgot to add in my question initially) is inside the instructor and student class instead of the Person class. Isn't the relation between Person and Instructor/Student a one-to-zero-or-one relationship!?

Comment: As for the Include, I assumed you absolutely had to Include the Student & Instructor classes for the data to eager load for some reason. It works. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick-ACNB: Yes, it is a one-to-zero-or-one relationship on database schema level. But it's not an explicit relationship for EF with a reference navigation property (it is somehow "hidden" in the TPT mapping). I think the mentioned limitation only means such explicit relationships.

Comment: I guess if I had another relation let's say inside the Instructor class like "public InstructorType Type {get;set;}" I couldn't eager load that one?

Comment: @Nick-ACNB: Yes, you couldn't. But I think it is another limitation than the one mentioned by Tom Dykstra which is very special (one-to-one relationship and TPH inheritance (you have TPT)).

Comment: "I guess if I had another relation let's say inside the Instructor class like "public InstructorType Type {get;set;}" I couldn't eager load that one?" <= you couldn't lazy load it either, could you? I just tried and it loaded the info, but I the relationship (InstructorType in your example) couldn't be loaded.